# Accessing Kivy layout size in kvlang

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror, nonetype, kivy-language

I have the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class TestGUI(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestGUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and the corresponding `.kv` file:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TestGUI>:
    temp_size: (0.5 * x for x in self.size)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.temp_size
```

The code does not run, throwing:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

due to the last line of code in the `kv` file. It seems that `self.size` is not initialized when `temp_size` is declared, but this raises a few questions.

- Why am I allowed to iterate through `self.size` when declaring `temp_size` if it is a `NoneType` object?
- Also, why does the code work perfectly fine when I replaces the last line with `size: (0.5 * x for x in self.size)` instead of using a variable?
- Also, how can I circumvent this issue and assign variables based on the value of `self.size`?

Comment: is it 'root' instead of 'self'? https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html

Comment: In this case, they're interchangeable, but I'm asking about a general case. For example, if the `TestGUI` was nested in a `BoxLayout`, then it would be `self.size`.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is basically this:

```
[x for x in None]
```

and *why* is it like that you can read in this [bug report](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4982). It's because the `canvas` isn't available yet and the properties seem to be calculated *after* it's created, therefore - if no `canvas`, then value == garbage.

To fix it you have to do it in the canvas itself like this and not *outside* in a property, because the canvas is built first:

```
<TestGUI>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: (0.5 * x for x in self.size)
```

I'm not sure what do you mean by the last question, though I think it might be either using properties *after* the `canvas` is already available, or using values from [`Config`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html) if you intend to use `Window` and not `Widget` size, or set the property in `__init__` and use it later in kv.

The latter one might be the best thing for you, but don't forget to:

- initialize with some values (`ListProperty([0, 0])`) otherwise the `Rectangle` will just kill the app
- use `super()`, for inheritance reasons

Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
Builder.load_string('''
<TestGUI>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.temp_size
''')


class TestGUI(BoxLayout):
    temp_size = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestGUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.size)
        self.temp_size = [0.5 * x for x in self.size]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestGUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: But if the canvas is built before the properties are initialized, then why does `self.size` not return `None` when setting the rectangle's size?

Comment: @Kootling I believe I missed a step or two that preceed the canvas creation. Most likely righr before the canvas is created, the size/pos/... properties are available to the canvas itself, but I believe the custom ones are created a moment after that. However, when used in the canvas, the custom property is calculated a moment *before* the canvas creation also, but even before canvas' size/pos/... are available (thus size/pos/... are None).

Comment: That makes more sense, but why do I get no error when setting `temp_size` to `[x for x in None]`? I only get the error when setting the rectangle's size to `temp_size`.

Comment: @Kootling Because of the order the property is evaluated. Try to print the value of the variable with on_* event.